# Decorator pattern: Why do we need an abstract decorator?

Tags: java, design-patterns, oop, decorator

This question was asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273943/question-about-decorator-pattern), but rather than answering the specific question, descriptions of how the decorator pattern works were given instead.  I'd like to ask it again because the answer is not immediately evident to me just by reading how the decorator pattern works (I've read the wikipedia article and the section in the book Head First Design Patterns).

Basically, I want to know why an abstract decorator class must be created which implements (or extends) some interface (or abstract class).  Why can't all the new "decorated classes" simply implement (or extend) the base abstract object themselves (instead of extending the abstract decorator class)?

To make this more concrete I'll use the example from the design patterns book dealing with coffee beverages:

- There is an abstract component class called `Beverage`
- Simple beverage types such as `HouseBlend` simply extend `Beverage`
- To decorate beverage, an abstract `CondimentDecorator` class is created which extends `Beverage` and has an instance of `Beverage`
- Say we want to add a "milk" condiment, a class `Milk` is created which extends `CondimentDecorator`

I'd like to understand why we needed the `CondimentDecorator` class and why the class `Milk` couldn't have simply extended the `Beverage` class itself and been passed an instance of `Beverage` in its constructor.

Hopefully this is clear...*if not* I'd simply like to know **why is the abstract decorator class necessary for this pattern**?  Thanks.

Edit: I tried to implement this, omitting the abstract decorator class, and it *seems* to still work.  Is this abstract class present in all descriptions of this pattern simply because it provides a standard interface for all of the new decorated classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It enables the decoration of the base class independently with various decorators in different combinations without having to derive a class for each possible combination.  For example, say you want your `Beverage` with milk and nutmeg.  Using decorators based on the abstract decorator class, you merely wrap with with `Milk` and `Nutmeg` decorators.  If it was derived from `Beverage`, you'd have to have a `MilkWithNutmegBeverage` class and a `MilkBeverage` class and a `NutmegBeverage` class.  You can imagine how this explodes as the number of possible combinations increases.  Using the abstract decorator implementation reduces this to just one decorator class implementation per decoration.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Yes, I am deriving 'Milk' from 'Beverage'; but 'Milk' is also being passed an instance of the 'Beverage' class which I would think is allowing me to wrap the classes as would be done with an abstract decorator class.

Comment: what I am trying to say is that with the abstract decorator class, all the new decorated classes inherit from it..so why can't we just remove the middle man (and have them inherit directly from 'Beverage' PLUS passing them an instance of beverage as was done before)?

Comment: I suppose you could do that, but as a child class it need not provide any additional behavior.  Conceptually, the decorator, even though it implements the same interface, is **not** actually an instance of the decorated class, but rather a helper class that augments the decorated class.  Basing it off a different abstract class exposes this design aspect and makes it clearer how new decorations are to be added.  Implementing the decorations as child classes blurs this distinction and leaves the implementation open to child classes that may break the decoration pattern unwittingly.

Comment: @es11: Ok, so you're deriving Milk from 'Beverage' -- what about 'Nutmeg' ? What happens if a consumer attempts to call Nutmeg.Drink() or worse, Nutmeg.PutOutFire()? 

If Nutmeg is a Beverage, then it should be able to serve as a beverage *even when it's not being used as a decorator of the beverage.* By making Nutmeg an instance of the abstract decorator, you prevent its being mistaken for an instance of the abstract class.

Comment: Conceptually the example of milk and nutmeg makes sense. However, how will the caller code to decorate the decorated twice? Say, call Milk(beverage) and then call Nutmeg(beverage), and I supposed it would still end up with a nutmeg beverage instead of a milk+nutmeg beverage..

Comment: @CCNA `Nutmeg(Milk(beverage))` - the decorator extends the same interface so you can compose them by passing a decorated `Beverage` into another decorator.

Comment: This answers what the original question explicitly was **not** about. Why is this accepted?

Answer (score 36):

Better one and a half year late than never:

A base class for decorators of a certain interface is not necessary.

However, it is very useful to have:

- for one thing, as a means of documenting that classes derived from it are decorators of the interface in question
- but mostly, because decorators usually do not need to add functionality to every single method of the decorated interface.

So, a base decorator class allows derived decorators to implement only those methods of the interface to which they actually need to add some functionality, leaving the rest of the methods to the base class to provide a default implementation for. (Which simply delegates the call to the decoree.)

Contrast this with writing decorators that implement the decorated interface from scratch, where the compiler requires that you provide an implementation for every single method of the interface, whether your decorator will be adding any functionality to it, or not.

It is that simple, really.

Comment: Why then a decorator can not be a subclass of a decoree? Thus we eliminate need of having an abstract decorator which provides non-decorated implementation (simply delegates) and also in case if a decoree will be added with new methods decorator still can be used without amending it (adding delegation)!

Comment: Huh? This did not make much sense. From the point of view of a decorator, the decoree is just an interface.  So, a decorator cannot be a subclass of a decoree, because you cannot subclass an interface.  You can _implement_ an interface, and that's precisely what a decorator does, by definition.

Comment: Now, if what you are trying to suggest here is to pick some concrete class which implements the interface, (assuming one is known,) and to subclass it to make a decorator out of it, this idea is nonsensical, because the decorator will be inheriting fields and functionality which it does not need, should not use, and has no business dealing with. I assume I did not understand your question, so perhaps you should start a new question on stack overflow and try to be as clear as possible regarding what you mean, so that it can receive a proper answer.

Comment: would be easier. if you can explain this with a help of an example.
This seems difficult to understand.

Answer (score 12):

I was wondering the same thing. Going back to the source, GOF Design Patterns, I see this under 'Implementation' in the Decorator chapter:

"Omitting the abstract Decorator class. There's no need to define an abstract Decorator class when you only need to add one responsibility. That's often the case when you're dealing with an existing class hierarchy rather than designing a new one. In that case, you can merge Decorator's responsilibility for forwarding requests to the component into the Concrete Decorator."

So at least in that case, it seems that GOF agree with you :-)

I'm not sure what the meaning of 'one responsibility' is. I'm not sure if more than 'one responsibility' would mean one concrete decorator that has more than one responsibility or more than one concrete decorator, each with its one responsibility. Either way, I don't see why the abstract Decorator is necessary. My guess is that tvanfosson's answer (in his comment on his own answer) is the right one - that once you start creating a number of decorating classes, it clarifies the design decision to group them under a superclass. On the other hand, where there is just one class, it perhaps makes the design decision less clear if you add in a second class that just sits as a pointless middle-man between base component and decorator (having said that, it's fairly likely that you'll want to add more at some point, so maybe better to include the abstract decorator even in the single case...)

At any rate, seems like it's to do with making the design clear, rather than the being the difference between the code working and not.

Answer (score 11):

(A bit late to your question..)

I also spent quite a while to try to figure out an answer. In my case the non-concrete Decorator extends the class to be decorated ("decoree"), instead of an interface common to both the decoree and the Decorator.

After reading from different sources, it seems to me that, besides what [tvanfosson said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016765/question-about-decorator-pattern-and-the-abstract-decorator-class/2016812#2016812), the reason to have the concrete decorators extend an abstract, or more general, decorator is so that we don't repeat the "delegation" code over and over again.

```
[Beverage]<———————[(abstract) CondimentDecorator]<—————[Milk]
[decoree ]——————<>[ adds code to efficiently    ]
                  [ forward calls to decorated  ]<—————[LemonJuice]
                  [ instance of Beverage        ]
```

In your case, your abstract decorator would extend the decoree and would implement the same interface as the decoree, delegating/forwarding all method calls to it. Then, the concrete decorators that you may build, would only need to implement those methods where you would want to do something different than just forward the method call to the decoree.

I hope I was clear.. :-S

Personally, I'm a bit disappointed at the need to repeat the decoree's interface in the decorator. This adds some coupling, since any time the decoree's interface changes (like getting more methods), the decorator needs to catch up.

In PHP 5.3.2 (yes, I know your question is related to Java), though, it should be possible to dynamically catch all method calls and forward them all, without the Decorator needing to know which methods are being called (in a not a very efficient way, though, having to use the Reflection API). I guess this is possible in Ruby and other languages already.

PS: This is my first answer ever in SO! ^_^

Comment: I kind of wish there was an (efficient) functionality like exception handling, where each level of a call stack has the opportunity to "catch" a method call and if it doesn't have a handler, pass it up. That would be hella decoupled. (and hell to debug).

Comment: In Java you can dynamically handle method calls for an interface with a [Dynamic Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html). Alternatively, or when you have a class rather than an interface, [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/)'s [Enhancer](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer.html) can generate implementation classes at runtime that delegate calls to a handler you provide.

Answer (score 5):

The base Decorator makes it easier to create additional decorators.  Imagine that Beverage has dozens of abstract methods, or is an interface, say stir(), getTemperature(), drink(), pour() and the like. Then your decorators all have to implement these methods for no other reason than to delegate them to the wrapped beverage, and your MilkyBeverage  and SpicyBeverage each have all those methods.

If instead you have a concrete BeverageDecorator class that extends or implements Beverage by simply delegating each call to the wrapped Beverage, subclasses can extend BeverageDecorator and only implement the methods they care about, leaving the base class to handle delegation.

This also protects you if the Beverage class (or interface) ever gains a new abstract method: all you need to do is add the method to the BeverageDecorator class. Without it, you would have to add that method to each and every Decorator you had created.

Answer (score 2):

actually i also sometimes leave out this 'middle-man' abstraction (if you don't have many decorator combinations). it decouples more but also adds complexity. in my view the main idea behind decorating is wrapping interfaces inside their own implementations.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the Decorator pattern, inheritance is being used for type matching. This is not the typical reason for sub-classing. The normal reason for sub-classing is to inherit behavior

To make this distinction clear, it makes sense to sub-class Beverage with CondimentDecorator because the CondimentDecorator class makes the distinction between a drink implementation (like DarkRoast) and condiment (like Mocha) clear. Consider for example you were tasked to come up with a menu for StarBuzz just by looking at the code. You would immediately know which are "base" beverages and which condiments by looking as the base class. DarkRoast's base class is Beverage. Mocha's base class is CondimentDecorator.

Still, I think it might make more sense in Java to implement the Beverage abstract class as an interface instead. According to the book, the code didn't use this approach because StarBuzz already had an abstract Beverage class (p 93) and an abstract base component is the historical approach to implementing the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The BaseDecorator (CondimentDecorator) class enforce the ConcreteDecortor (Milk) to have a base abtract class (Brevrage) in input in the constructor.

If the BaseDecorator class does not exist, it does not force you to implement a decorator that require a BaseAbstractClass in input. It is the goal of the Decorator Pattern to enforce input and ouput of classes.

(I think you take your example from Head First Design Pattern, and in their example, the BaseDecorator class do not have this contructor).

Comment: acutally , u can't add an constructor to an abstract class . so the "enforce" doesn't seem to be .

Comment: @JasonHuang: That's wrong. In Java you can add constructors to abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

maybe years too late but here is the point with the gof statement of single responsibiltiy.

suppose the abstract decorator also have additional methods not own by the component (abstract) there by the decarator have multiple responsibilty.

this ensure that the component is always reuseable for it should implements all abstract / interface of the component but must not implements the decorator additional responsibilty.

any program that use the component(abstract) can ensure the component works accordingly in the utilization wise(into running object) and concrtete creation of the component(abstract). thus this will ensure program integrity and ease of development and expandsion of application/program.

thus decorator will leave those alove and then as though stand as his own object to be use in any manner as possible include manners similar to above.
eg. decorator being decorated.(just an idea)

great isnt it? (clap)

Comment: I think you might be on to something re: "ensure that the component is always reuseable", but I can't quite fully understand what you are saying. Could you elaborate?