# Generic method to perform a map-reduce operation. (Java-8)

Tags: java, function, generics, java-8, overloading

How to overload a Function with generic parameter in Java 8?

```
public class Test<T> {

    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public int sum(Function<T, Integer> function) {
        return list.stream().map(function).reduce(Integer::sum).get();
    }


    public double sum(Function<T, Double> function) {
        return list.stream().map(function).reduce(Double::sum).get();
    }
}
```

> Error: java: name clash: 
>   sum(java.util.function.Function<T,java.lang.Double>) and 
>   sum(java.util.function.Function<T,java.lang.Integer>) have the same erasure

Comment: Same as Java 7, 6 and 5: you can't. That's what the message tells you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you present in your question has got nothing to do with Java 8 and everything to do with how generics work in Java. `Function<T, Integer> function` and `Function<T, Double> function` will go through [type-erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) when compiled and will be transformed to `Function`. The rule of thumb for method overloading is to have different number, type or sequence of parameters. Since both your methods will transform to take a `Function` argument, the compiler complains about it.

That being said, [srborlongan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3475600/srborlongan) has already provided one way to resolve the issue. The problem with that solution is that you have to keep modifying your `Test` class for each and every type of operation (addition,subtraction,etc) on different types (Integer,Double, etc). An alternate solution would be to use `method overriding` instead of `method overloading` :

Change the `Test` class a bit as follows :

```
public abstract class Test<I,O extends Number> {

    List<I> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public O performOperation(Function<I,O> function) {
        return list.stream().map(function).reduce((a,b)->operation(a,b)).get();
    }

    public void add(I i) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    public abstract O operation(O a,O b);
}
```

Create a subclass of `Test` that will add two `Integer`s.

```
public class MapStringToIntAddtionOperation extends Test<String,Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer operation(Integer a,Integer b) {
        return a+b;
    }

}
```

Client code can then use the above code as follows :

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    Test<String,Integer> test = new MapStringToIntAddtionOperation();
    test.add("1");
    test.add("2");
    System.out.println(test.performOperation(Integer::parseInt));
}
```

The advantage of using this approach is that your `Test` class is in line with the `open-closed` principle. To add a new operation such as multiplication, all you have to do is add a new subclass of `Test` and `override` the `operation` method to multiply two numbers. Club this with the [Decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273943/question-about-decorator-pattern) pattern and you can even minimize the number of sub-classes that you have to create.

**Note** The example in this answer is indicative. There are a lot of areas of improvement (such as make `Test` a functional interface instead of an abstract class) which are beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: It's a lot easier to just use different method names :) `sumInt, sumDouble`

Comment: That can be easily arranged by making `operation` a `protected` method in `Test`, creating a `sumXYZ` method in the subclass and calling the overriden `operation` method in it. :)  But like I said, there are a lot of areas of improvement that are beyond the scope of the answer..

Answer (score 6):

[Benji Weber once wrote of a way to circumvent this.](http://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2015/02/20/work-around-java-same-erasure-errors-with-lambdas/) What you need to do is to define custom functional interfaces that extend the types for your parameters:

```
public class Test<T> {

    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ToIntFunction extends Function<T, Integer>{}
    public int sum(ToIntegerFunction function) {
        return list.stream().map(function).reduce(Integer::sum).get();
    }


    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ToDoubleFunction extends Function<T, Double>{}
    public double sum(ToDoubleFunction function) {
        return list.stream().map(function).reduce(Double::sum).get();
    }
}
```

Another way is to use java.util.function.ToIntFunction and java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction instead:

```
public class Test<T> {

    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @FunctionalInterface
    public int sum(ToIntFunction function) {
        return list.stream().mapToInt(function).sum();
    }

    public double sum(ToDoubleFunction function) {
        return list.stream().mapToDouble(function).sum();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion of using a wrapper interface is good but not "clean" because `Test` needs to be modified everytime a new operation or a new type needs to be introduced. With just two types (Integer or Doble) and two operations (sum and multiply), you need 4 methods . Not to mention the wrapper interfaces that you have to create for each type. That's an explosion of the API. +1 for the link though.

Comment: This doesn't work very well:) See for a similar example [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) `comparingDouble(ToDoubleFunction)`, `comparingInt(ToIntFunction)` - The methods have different names, because overloading is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

@srborlongan 's solution won't work very well :)

See a similar example - [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) methods - `comparingDouble(ToDoubleFunction)`, `comparingInt(ToIntFunction)`, etc.  The methods have different names, because overloading is not a good idea here.

The reason is, when you do `sum(t->{...})`, the compiler is unable to infer which method to call; actually it needs to resolve method overloading first, to pick one method, before inferring the type of the implicit lambda expression (based on that method's signature)

This is disappointing. In the earlier stage, Java8 had a more sophisticated inference engine, and `Comparator` had overloaded `comparing()` methods; and `sum(t->{...})` would be correctly inferred too. Unfortunately, they decided to simply it :( And here we are now.

Rule of thumb for overloading methods with functional arguments: the arities of the functional interfaces must be different, unless both are 0.

```
// OK, different arity
m1( X->Y )
m1( (X1, X2)->Y )

// not OK, both are arity 1
m2( X->Y )
m2( A->B )

    m2( t->{...} ); // fail; type of `t` cannot be inferred 

// OK! both are arity 0
m3( ()->Y )
m3( ()->B )
```

The reason why overloading with arity 0 is OK is that the lambda expressions won't be implicit - all argument types are known (because there's no argument!), we don't need contextual information for inferring the lambda type

```
m3( ()-> return new Y() );   // lambda type is ()->Y
m3( ()-> return new B() );   // lambda type is ()->B
```