# Method overload attempt gives name clash error. Not using Generics

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, overloading

I have the following code.

```
public class myClass {

    public static void myMethod(
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> src,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> dest,
            Integer[] selectedIndices) {

    }

    public static void myMethod(
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> src,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> dest,
            Integer[] selectedIndices) {

    }
}
```

I am expecting an overload of `myMethod` but the compiler complains of `name clash` error. Upon searching SO, I found  a related (probably, not sure) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30826674/842808), but I am not using Generics. So my methods don't go through the [type-Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html). Can someone explain what am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean "I am not using Generics"?

Comment: @PeterRader I mean, my method signature does not have anything like <T> in it.

Comment: <T> is a placeholder for <Double> and <Integer>. You are using generics.

Comment: He thinks <T> is a Generic but <Double> not. Its just a confusion that solved in the comments.

Comment: @PeterRader How does java decide what is generic and what is not? By looking at <> ? So here, Java compiler sees <Integer> and <Double> as some <T> ?

Comment: Yes, by looking at <> outside of comments and outside of string/char-sequeces! The smallest generic-operator is the diamond-operator `<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one important point here. **You are still using Generics in your code.**

Consider these 2 LOC

1. `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> src`
2. `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> src`

Java internally, in the implementation of these collection classes is using generics only to handle both of these situation and hence you face [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) problem.

---

**EDIT**

Just look at this `ArrayList` class
*(It is usually at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\src.zip\java\util\ArrayList.java)*

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    ...
    ...
    public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        elementData = c.toArray();
        size = elementData.length;
        // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
        if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
            elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
    }
    ...
    ...
```

As you can see the internal structure is using generics as you expected.

Comment: How does java decide what is generic and what is not? By looking at <> ? So here, Java compiler sees <Integer> and <Double> as some <T> ?

Comment: @Abhinav see the actual structure of `ArrayList` in my edited answer. You'll understand yourself what's happening behind the scenes

Answer (score 3):

When you are doing this `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> src` **you are definitely using generics**. and due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html),

- `Integer` information will be lost, i.e. all generic information will be lost
- `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> src` and `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> src` will be same.
- So, method signature will be same for both methods you have defined which will not qualify for overloading.

To solve this, you can declare your methods as below and read about [generics wildcard operator](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/28/generics-the-wildcard-operator/)

```
ArrayList<ArrayList< ? extends Number>> src
```

Here, `Number` is a superclass for both `Integer` and `Double`. So your class will be as below

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void myMethod(
            ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Number>> src,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Number>> dest,
            Integer[] selectedIndices) {
    }
}
```

You can pass an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` or `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>` to it.

Comment: thanks. May be my fundamental on Generics is weak. But am I not specifying exactly what the function can expect. E.g. ArrayList and Integer. Can these be considered Generics?

Comment: How does java decide what is generic and what is not? By looking at <> ? So here, Java compiler sees <Integer> and <Double> as some <T> ?

Comment: If you use < >(angular brackets) that means you are directly or indirectly using the generics. In this case you are using the predefined Generic List i.e ArrayList which supports every Datatype using Generics(Generic Data type<T> ).

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely using generics, and type erasure is taking place. You cold do the following

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static <T> void myMethod(
        ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> src,
        ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> dest,
        Integer[] selectedIndices) {

    }
}
```

**EDIT1:**
To answer your question in the comment. It derives the type from the parameters passed in. Here is an example on how to use it. I also added a line which will cause the compiler to fail, because they types of the arguments don't match.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static <T> void myMethod(
        ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> src,
        ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> dest,
        Integer[] selectedIndices) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> srcInteger = null;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<BigDecimal>> srcBigDecimal = null;
        Integer[] indexes = null;

        myMethod(srcInteger, srcInteger, indexes);
        myMethod(srcBigDecimal, srcBigDecimal, indexes);
        myMethod(srcInteger, srcBigDecimal, indexes); // <- this will not compile
    }
}
```

Comment: How does java decide what is generic and what is not? By looking at <> ? So here, Java compiler sees <Integer> and <Double> as some <T> ?