# Ambiguous lambda overload in Guava Futures

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8, overloading

I believe I am facing an eclipse bug here, but I'd like to confirm.
I am using java 8 (jdk 1.8.0_102), and my code compiles normally, but eclipse gives me an error.

My code looks like this:

```
public ListenableFuture<ProtoBufExchange> myMethod(
   //some code here
   return Futures.transform(future,(Request.Builder reqBuilder) -> {

    //some code here

    return Futures.immediateFuture(exchange);
  }
```

The error shown in eclipse is this:

> The method transform(ListenableFuture<Request.Builder>, AsyncFunction<? super Request.Builder,? extends 
>   ProtoBufExchange>) is ambiguous for the type Futures.

If I put a cast, eclipse will not complain:

```
public ListenableFuture<ProtoBufExchange> myMethod(
   //some code here
   return Futures.transform(future,(AsyncFunction<Request.Builder, ProtoBufExchange>) (Request.Builder reqBuilder) -> {

    //some code here

    return Futures.immediateFuture(exchange);
  }
```

I know the guava 15.0 Future.transform() is overloaded, with the two forms below (on newer guava versions the async method has a different name):

```
transform(ListenableFuture<I> input, Function<? super I,? extends O> function)
```

or

```
transform(ListenableFuture<I> input, AsyncFunction<? super I,? extends O> function)
```

But somehow the jdk compiler resolves this ambiguation. Maybe because in the code above, if we were implementing a Function, rather than an AsyncFunction, the return type of Futures.transform would not match with the method return type.

Is it a bug on eclipse? Am I missing something here?

More details on my environment:

jdk: 1.8.0_102
eclipse: 4.6.2
guava: 15.0

Comment: Does eclipse use the same `java` setup that you used to run your program outside eclipse?

Comment: @CKing Eclipse has its own Java compiler (ecj) so it is possible to get different results from Eclipse and javac.

Comment: @greg-449 I see. I haven't encountered such a scenario before so wasn't aware of the same.

Comment: Arguably, the overloaded methods `transform(A->B)` and `transform(A->F<B>)` are inherently prune to ambiguity, especially when supplied with an implicit lamba as argument. Language spec aside, it is really difficult for a programmer to reason about it and understand which method is picked. In Java, an API designer ought not to create overloaded methods like that. Of course, to be fair, this guava API was designed way before Java 8 spec was finalized. The situation is very much like `map` and `flatMap` - it's better to use 2 different method names.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/30831291/2158288

Comment: Are you sure that javac allows that? Looking at Guava, both `Function` and `AsyncFunction` are interfaces, and neither inherits the other, neither is more specific than the other. So _actually_ compiler is not supposed to select either of them, it should make compilation error, exactly what Eclipse compiler did. Return values do not matter here.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: it does. And the Eclipse version, I tested, does too. `AsyncFunction` doesn’t need to extend `Function` to be more specific, when a lambda expression is passed as argument.

Comment: @Holger, so, after reading your answer, it _is_ Eclipse compiler error in one of the earlier versions. Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a distinction between “explicitly typed lambda expressions” and “implicitly typed lambda expressions”.

An implicitly typed lambda expression of the form `name -> expressiorOrBlock` or `(name[,name]*) -> expressionOrBlock` requires its context, i.e. a resolved method, to determine its type, hence isn’t used to disambiguate overloaded methods. It wouldn’t be impossible to do this, but due to the resulting complexity, it was explicitly ruled out by the specification.

Explicitly typed lambda expressions of the form `(Type name[, Type name]*) -> expressionOrBlock` have everything needed to determine their functional signature, including their return type, which allows to use them to disambiguate overloaded methods.

To provide a simple example:

```
interface F<T,R> {
    R apply(T t);
}
interface AF<T,R> {
    Future<R> apply(T t);
}
static <T,R> Future<R> method(F<T,R> f) {
    return null;
}
static <T,R> Future<R> method(AF<T,R> f) {
    return null;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // these two don't compile
    method(x -> "bla");
    method(x -> new FutureTask<String>(null));

    // these two do compile
    method((Object x) -> "bla");
    method((Object x) -> new FutureTask<String>(null));
}
```

The formal rules are specified in [JLS, §15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), but it also contains an informal hint:

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

I think, it’s easy to see that every call that can be handled by `method(AF)` could also be handled by `method(F)`, while the opposite doesn’t apply, i.e. the `method((Object x) -> "bla")` invocation can only be handled by `method(F)`, so it’s not ambiguous, whereas `method((Object x) -> new FutureTask<String>(null))` could be handled by both, but `method(AF)` is *more specific*.

The [relevant formal part](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5-310) is:

> A functional interface type `S` is more specific than a functional interface type `T` for an expression `e` if `T` is not a subtype of `S` and one of the following is true (where `U₁` ... `Uk` and `R₁` are the parameter types and return type of the function type of the capture of `S`, and `V₁` ... `Vk` and `R₂` are the parameter types and return type of the function type of `T`):
>
> - If e is an explicitly typed lambda expression (§15.27.1), then one of the following is true:
>
>   - `R₂` is `void`.
>   - `R₁` `<:` `R₂`.
>   - …

So in this specific case involving an explicitly typed lambda expression, the return type of the functional type is already sufficient to disambiguate.

But note that compiling the example code also produces the warning:

> warning: [overloads] `<T#1,R#1>method(F<T#1,R#1>)` … is potentially ambiguous with `<T#2,R#2>method(AF<T#2,R#2>)`

Reminding that implicitly typed lambda expressions will always be ambiguous with such overloaded methods and also the method selection with explicitly type lambda expressions might not be intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To be honest, I didn't understand the formal specification, but if your understanding is right: "the return type of the functional type is already sufficient to disambiguate", then this explains why the code does compile. Which also takes us to the conclusion that this is indeed a bug in eclipse compiler. Right?

Comment: Exactly. I know, the formal specification is hard to read. That’s why I also cited the “informal intuition” part.