# Java var and inference type ambiguity

Tags: java, type-inference, java-10

Both calls are correct:

```
Collectors.groupingBy((String s)->s.toLowerCase(),Collectors.counting());
Collectors.groupingBy((String s)->s.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH),Collectors.counting());
```

Since then, why the following one is wrong:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,Collectors.counting());
```

after all `String::toLowerCase` can not correspond to the second one... Then why IntelliJ says `Reference to 'toLowerCase' is ambiguous, both 'toLowerCase(Locale)' and 'toLowerCase()' match`?

`String::toLowerCase` must be unambiguously resolved to `(String s)->s.toLowerCase()` or did I miss something?

Of course if I put more context to IntelliJ like:

```
Collector<String,?,Map<String,Long>> c = Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,Collectors.counting());
```

that is correct, but alas in Java 10 var inference type context it is wrong:

```
var c = Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,Collectors.counting());
```

I understand that compiler can not infer the input type of `counting`. If I write:

```
Collector<String,?,Long> counter = Collectors.counting();
var c = Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,counter);
```

it it correct. Thus again, why compiler is not able to infer the only acceptable form?

-------EDIT--------

I used IntelliJ/compiler interchangeably just because I used IntelliJ first and error reported was :

```
Reference to 'toLowerCase' is ambiguous, both 'toLowerCase(Locale)' and 'toLowerCase()' match
```

Compiler's error was much much more unreadable (but contains more hints on why inference fails), something like:

```
Demo.java:31: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1,K,A,D,CAP#1,T#2
        Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,Collectors.counting());
                             ^
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Locale)
  where T#1,K,A,D,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1,K,A,D>groupingBy(Function<? super T#1,? extends K>,Collector<? super T#1,A,D>)
    K extends Object declared in method <T#1,K,A,D>groupingBy(Function<? super T#1,? extends K>,Collector<? super T#1,A,D>)
    A extends Object declared in method <T#1,K,A,D>groupingBy(Function<? super T#1,? extends K>,Collector<? super T#1,A,D>)
    D extends Object declared in method <T#1,K,A,D>groupingBy(Function<? super T#1,? extends K>,Collector<? super T#1,A,D>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>counting()
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: "Then why IntelliJ says" are you saying this only happens in intellij, or does it happen with another compiler too?

Comment: Same on Eclipse: the compiler seems to infer the type argument of `Collectors.counting()` as `Object`, hence it expects that `String` has a method `toLowerCase(Object)`.

Comment: Java 14 on Netbeans, Windows here. Same problem. The compiler error disappears if I typecast the method reference: `(Function<String, String>) String::toLowerCase`.

Comment: @AndyTurner well in fact compiler reports error that are "interpreted" by intellij to make them more "readable".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is compiler "weakness", at least until [this JEP is in place](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/302).

I have already answered almost the same exact question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169639/function-and-predicate-parameter-ambiguous/50169759#50169759). There is also another [answer from JDK core developers too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905169/java8-ambiguity-with-lambdas-and-overloaded-methods/21951311#21951311).

There is also [yet another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276988/method-reference-is-ambiguous-for-thread-sleep) that is very close to yours.

What matters is that this is known to cause a problem, at times, but has a trivial solution - use a `lambda`, and thus an *explicit* type, according to the `JLS`.

Comment: You don’t need a lambda here, as you normally don’t invoke `Collectors.groupingBy` as a statement nor assign it to a variable. Just use it as an argument to `collect` on a `Stream` and there’s no problem…

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the compiler is finding two occurrences of `toLowerCase` in the `String` class, so it decides to first infer from the second argument, `Collectors.counting()`, which is resolved to `Object`. This leads the compiler to throw an error because it can't find any `toLowerCase()` method accepting an `Object`.

If we try to define a method to use it as replacement:

```
static String toLowerCase(String s) {
    return s.toLowerCase();
}
```

the following would then work:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(Test::toLowerCase, Collectors.counting()); // compiles ok
```

But if we introduce another overload, the problem appears again:

```
static String toLowerCase(String s) {
    return s.toLowerCase();
}

static String toLowerCase(String s, Locale locale) {
    return s.toLowerCase(locale);
}

Collectors.groupingBy(Test::toLowerCase,Collectors.counting()); // fails again
```

Comment: Good reference, but not exactly the problem since I do not use any generic method reference here. But almost the same problem...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Actually you're right it's not exactly the same, because in that reported bug, the `get()` method is not overloaded. But I still think it's a problem due to overloaded method resolution