# Why does method referencing show compiler error in scenario 1 but works in scenario 2?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream, comparator

I have created following list

```
   List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(4, 5, -2, 0, -3, -1, -5, -4);
```

`Scenario 1`

This line does not work. shows compiler error

```
    System.out.println(list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Math::abs).thenComparing(Integer::intValue))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

`Scenario 2`

But the below line work properly when we interchange the position of `Math::abs` and `Integer::intValue`

```
System.out.println(list.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Integer::intValue).thenComparing(Math::abs))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

`Scenario 3`

Also this line work properly when `Math::abs` is replaced by `byAbs` function object

```
Function<Integer, Integer> byAbs = Math::abs;

System.out.println(list.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(byAbs).thenComparing(Integer::intValue))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

`Scenario 4`

This line also working fine when i replace `Math::abs` to `(Integer x)-> Math.abs(x)`

```
System.out.println(list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Integer x)-> Math.abs(x)).thenComparing(Integer::intValue))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

`Scenario 5`

Again if I remove `.thenComparing(Integer::intValue)` from the Comparator it works fine.

```
System.out.println(list.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Math::abs))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Compiler shows error on `Comparator.comparing(Math::abs)` and it states:

- Cannot infer type argument(s) for <T, U> comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>)
- The type Math does not define abs(Object) that is applicable here

What is the actual logic behind it ?

Comment: Probably, a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66278909/10819573

Comment: I have added the next scenario i.e Scenario 2 that actually working when we interchange the position of Math::abs and Integer::value. @ArvindKumarAvinash

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to the problem encountered by the compiler when resolving overloaded methods when using method references, as documented in http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/302 (section on *Optional: Better disambiguation for functional expression*).

This applies here because `Math.abs` has many overloads.

Comment: if it is so then it must also work in scenario 2 but its working. @NightShade