# decorator design pattern for adding new methods and codes to the existing object

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I am new in design patterns. I am trying to use decorator design pattern to add new codes and functionalities to my existing app.

Suppose I have a class of App which has two methods "Add" and "Multiply". At some point (run time) the app will require to calculate the average as well. 
So, I am trying to use decorator design pattern to make this possible.

So far I have :

```
public class App implements Code{
  public int a=2;
  public int b=3;

  @Override
  public int Add(int a, int b) {
    int add;
    add = a+b;
    return add;
  }

  @Override
  public int Multiply(int a, int b) {
    int mul;
    mul= a*b;
    return mul;
  }

}
```

In order to do this I define an interface "Code" like this:

```
public interface Code {
  public int Add (int a, int b);
  public int Multiply (int a, int b);     
}
```

and then a decorator abstract class `CodeExtention`

```
public abstract class CodeExtention implements Code{
  protected Code extendedCode;

  public CodeExtention(Code extendedCode) {
    this.extendedCode = extendedCode;
  }

  @Override
  public  int Multiply(int a, int b){
    return extendedCode.Multiply(a, b);
  }

  @Override
  public  int Add(int a, int b){
    return extendedCode.Add(a, b);
  }

}
```

Now I define a concert class "AVG" extended from my abstract class like this :

```
public class AVG extends CodeExtention{

  public AVG(Code extendedCode) {
    super(extendedCode);
  }

  public int AVGcalculator (int a, int b){
    return (a+b)/2;    
  }

  @Override
  public int Add(int a, int b) {
    return super.Add(a, b); 
  }

  @Override
  public int Multiply(int a, int b) {
    return super.Multiply(a, b); 
  }          
}
```

Now I expect that my app can calculate the average to do so I have in my main :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Code app = new App();
    app = new AVG(app);
  }   
}
```

Here I can have :

```
System.out.println(app.Add(3, 4));
System.out.println(app.Multiply(3, 4));
```

I still cannot have:

```
System.out.println(app.AVGcalculator(3, 4));
```

I don't know what is wrong, or even if I can use this design pattern for my scenario!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is of type Code since AVGcalculator is not part of Code interface you cannot call it if you want to call for AVGcalculator you can do it like this

```
System.out.println(((AVG)app).AVGcalculator(3, 4));
```

Comment: Thanks I would like to know if is it the correct way of adding new methods to my objects at runtime ?

Comment: Could you please explain what is "((AVG)app)" ?

Comment: Its is called casting it basically means turning one type to another. But of course it is not always possible for example you cannot cast Integer into Date . I suggest you read about casting here is a nice link https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/

Comment: Thanks, is it the correct way of adding new methods to my objects at runtime ? do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: No it is not. Decorator does not add new method at run time it adds new behavior at runtime .

Answer (score 3):

The decorator pattern is a really bad choice for this.

The decorator fulfills the same contract — the same API — as the decorated object. What you want is to change the contract. Thus, the pattern isn't applicable (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274234/1360803) for a good example when to use a decorator).

What you can do is using the *Command* pattern:

```
interface BinaryIntOperation {
    int execute(int a, int b);
}

class AddOperation implements BinaryIntOperation {
    int execute(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

 class MultiplyOperation implements BinaryIntOperation {
    int execute(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }
}

 class AverageOperation implements BinaryIntOperation {
    int execute(int a, int b) {
        return (a + b)/2;
    }
}
```

You can then do many thing from there:

```
BinaryIntOperation op = new AddOperation();
System.out.println(op.execute(3, 4));

op = new MultiplyOperation();
System.out.println(op.execute(4, 5));
```

You can also write things like that:

```
public int[] execute(int[] arr, BinaryIntOperation op, int a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = op.execute(a, arr[i]);
    return arr;
}
```

The *command* pattern is a behavioral pattern, which seems more like what you want (changing behavior).

Note that in C#, you could do *exactly* what you want by using *extension methods*. But Java doesn't have those.

Comment: Actually I don't want to change a behaviour. I want to add a new behaviour. For example my app can Add and Multiply now but I want it to be able to calculate average in addition to its previous capabilities.I want to show that is is capable to be evolved! The reason why I don't want to give it all capabilities at the beginning is to reduce the overhead of having extra codes.  Actually I am building an smart object which is able to grow (get evolved) by adding new functionalities to itself. My aim is to built a modular structure to my object. For example if it needs a security module .

Comment: If it needs a security module, the code for security could be added or if it needs communication module a code related to communication to be added to its base codes ... see this image http://cdn.crowdfundinsider.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Blocks-Modular-Smart-Watch.jpg  this is a modular watch .. it has a core component and you can add/remove different modules and customise your watch based on your need. if you need a hart monitoring you can add a module , if you need GPS you can add GPS module etc. I need to make a similar structure for my object .. to add/remove different code modules..

Comment: You can *not* add behavior with a decorator. You can *modify existing behavior* with a decorator. You are using the wrong pattern. Use simple composition to create such modular objects.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more ?

Comment: How to use simple composition to creat such modular objects ... Could you please give an example on my scenario by editing my codes ? Thanks

Comment: I already gave you a code example. You can easily create an object from there that holds a list or map of `BinaryIntOperations` and is easily exetendable with more of them. But for an in-depth explanation of design-patterns this is the wrong format, this is an Q&A site. The only really helpful thing I can say is that you are using the wrong pattern. But there is no single, canonical answer as to what you could do else. The pool of possible solutions is way too broad to be touched on here.